# What kind of regression model to use, with multiple target variables?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, python, optimization

With normal Machine Learning we are focusing on 1 target variable. However, I have a case where I want to see the 'pattern' of the X-values/ predictors on 5 (instead of 1) target variable(s).

The data has something like 20 predictors (X variables) and of course 5 target variables.

**My question:** I want to answer the question, what would be the optimal for all the X-values, in order to get all the Target variables 'as high as possible'.

I was thinking of making 1 target variable (combining the other 5 targets, into 1. However, this was not really working). Other thoughts were an optimization model, or a 'Multi Target Regression' (although there are not a lot of examples outside).

Anyone an idea what kind of model is suitable for this? Really appreciate your help! With an example (in hopefully Python), it would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

You could just perform 5 independent regressions. If you use scikit-learn, you can do it in one step as LinearRegression supports multiple target variables, as documented 
[here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit).

Comment: That would't show the complete relations, right? It will only show the relations per regression model, instead of taking all the variables into account. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I think you'd see all relations. If you had 2 dependent and 2 independent variables, your system would look as follows:

Y1 = a11 + b11 * X1 + b12*X2 and 
Y2 = a21 + b21 * X1 + b22*X2.

What other relations are you interested in?

Comment: If the model is linear regression (without regularization) as you describe, the target variables _can’t_ affect each other. This isn’t the case if you feed some (predicted) targets in to guide prediction of the others. Another option is to include some form of parameter-tying or depth in the model.